# SQL query selecting whole table except for records defined in 'ignore_table'

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm using Mysql to store some records (there won't be more than 150, 200). Sql servers are pretty fast and optimized when processing queries but my problem is that the connection is slow and high-latency and I don't want to execute more queries than absolutely needed. My tables look as follows:

```
some_table:
ID  Name    Start   Duration
-----------------------------
1   rec1    0       15
2   rec2    0       25
3   arc3    15      15
4   rac4    30      30

ignore_table:
ID  rec_id  day
----------------
1   2       0
2   3       1
3   3       2
```

I'd like to select all records from `some_table` except those which should be ignored in given day (this will be actually the only thing that varies in whole query).

Let's say current day is 1, so my I want to execute some query which will return:

```
ID  Name    Start   Duration
-----------------------------
1   rec1    0       15
2   rec2    0       25
4   rac4    30      30
```

The record with ID 3 was removed, because of 2nd record in `ignore_table` - it says that on day one we should ignore record with ID equal 3.

I used to select all records from `some_table` and then individually check every single of them to see if they shall or shall not be ignored. That worked with small ammount of data on localhost, but in the real app I'd really prefer something faster.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:

```
SELECT s.* FROM some_table s
  LEFT JOIN ignore_table i ON s.ID = i.rec_id AND i.day = 1
  WHERE i.ID IS NULL;
```

Or:

```
SELECT s.* FROM some_table s
  WHERE s.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT i.rec_id FROM ignore_table i WHERE i.day = 1
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Didn't know about the first one... Looks odd... Which one is in your opinion faster? I have ~100 records in some_table and about 600 in ignore_table :)

Comment: I think that both will be fast enough. But if you want, it is good to test both queries using `EXPLAIN` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use subselect for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   some_table 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT rec_id 
                  FROM   ignore_table 
                  WHERE  day = 2)
```